# Comprobar si una mesa tiene valor de promoción

Tags: php, sql

Tengo una tabla que almacena la compra del usuario que está en la siguiente estrutura:

**tb_cart**

```
 cart_name | cart_price | car_promotion_price | cart_amount
 Coca-Cola       2.50               1.00            2
```

Y me gustaría mostrar el monto total de la compra. Para eso, estoy hacienda lo siguiente:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($this->conexao, "SELECT SUM(P.product_price * C.cart_amount) AS ValorTotal
       FROM pd_cart C
       INNER JOIN pd_order_status S ON S.status_cart_token = C.cart_token 
       INNER JOIN pd_products P ON C.cart_id_product = P.product_id
       WHERE C.cart_token = '".$_SESSION["TOKEN"]."'
       AND S.status_order = 'A';");
$pd = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);        
return $pd->ValorTotal; // return 5.00 cuando debería ser 2.00
```

El problema es que no soy capaz de calcular el valor promocional.
¿Cómo incluiría esta consulta cuando el producto tiene valor promocional?

Answer (score 0):

Faltan detalles en tu pregunta para dar una respuesta 100% certera, sin embargo me quiero aventurar con una posible solución.

Usando la sentencia `CASE` puedes validar si el producto tiene precio promocional o **viene vacío o tiene valor cero** (*aquí desconozco la estructura de tus tablas*) y de acuerdo a esa información se hace el cálculo con uno u otro valor.

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(
            (CASE 
            WHEN P.car_promotion_price IS NULL THEN P.product_price 
            ELSE P.car_promotion_price 
            END) AS price * C.cart_amount
          ) AS ValorTotal
          FROM pd_cart C
          INNER JOIN pd_order_status S ON S.status_cart_token = C.cart_token 
          INNER JOIN pd_products P ON C.cart_id_product = P.product_id
          WHERE C.cart_token = '".$_SESSION["TOKEN"]."'
          AND S.status_order = 'A';";

$sql = mysqli_query($this->conexao, $query);

$pd = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);
```

Intenta con este método ajustándolo a tus datos y a tu estructura y comenta como te va.